# Bernoulli-Shift is a stationary process

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory, stationary-processes

Let be $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})=([0,1), \mathcal{B}([0,1)), \lambda)$. We define $Y_n : \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ by $Y_n := 2Y_{n-1} \mod 1$. Many sources claim that this is a stationary process with help of the following theorem:

Let $(X_n)_n$ be stationary with values in $\mathcal{S^{\mathbb{N}}}$, then $(Y_k)_k$ with $Y_k=g(X_k, X_{k+1},..)$ for measurable $g : \mathcal{S^{\mathbb{N}}} \rightarrow T$ is stationary too.

I understand some ideas of the proof. To be precise, we start with a construction of iid sequence of bernoulli random variables $X_i$ with values in $\mathcal{S}=\{0,1\}$, $\mathbb{P}^*(X_i=0)=\mathbb{P}^*(X_i=1)=1/2$. Lets denote with $(\Omega^*,\mathcal{P}^* ,\mathbb{P}^*)$ the product space. Further we define $g$ as follows

$g: \Omega^* \rightarrow \Omega \\ g((w_n)_n ) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty w_n 2^{-(n+1)}$

I managed to show that $(\mathbb{P}^*)^g=\lambda$. I can use the theorem and show that $Z_k=g(X_k, X_{k+1},..)$ are stationary. I was able even to show that $2Z_{k-1} = Z_k$, but $Z_k$ are not $Y_k$ they live on different space. No idea how to conclude that $Y_k$ are stationary too.

Comment: Consider adding a tag for a broader subject area to which the question belongs. Some of [these tags](//math.stackexchange.com/tags/ergodic-theory/info#h-related-tags) might fit. *(autocomment)*

Comment: The distributions of the proceses $(Y_k)$ and $(Z_k)$ coincide hence $(Y_k)$ is stationary if and only if $(Z_k)$ is.